# Create ArrayList of arrays using Arrays.asList

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create ArrayList of arrays with method Arrays.asList but I am struggling to achieve this goal when I have only one array to pass into the list.

```java
List<String[]> notWithArrays = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Slot"}); // compiler does not allow this
List<String[]> withArrays = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Slot"},new String[] {"ts"}); // this is ok
```

The problem is that sometimes I have only one array to pass as argument and since it is only one iterable method asList creates List of strings out of it instead of required List<String[]>. Is there a way or method to make the list of arrays *notWithArrays* without having to create it manually?

Example of creating it manually:

```java
List<String[]> withArraysManual = new ArrayList<>();
withArraysManual.add(new String[] {"Slot"});
```

Comment: You mean `Arrays.asList(new String[][] {{"Slot"}});` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to create a `List<String[]>` using `Arrays.asList`, containing the string array `{"Slot"}`.

You can do that like this:

```
List<String[]> notWithArrays = Arrays.asList(new String[][] {{"Slot"}});
```

or you can explicitly specify the generic type parameter to `asList`, like this:

```
List<String[]> notWithArrays = Arrays.<String[]>asList(new String[] {"Slot"});
```

Comment: Another way would be to use `List<String[]> notWithArrays = Collections.singletonList(new String[]{"Slot"});`

Answer (score 5):

`Arrays.asList` has a varargs parameter, `T...`. The issue that you’re facing is that Java has two ways of calling a method with a vararg parameter:

1. With multiple arguments of type `T`
2. With a single argument of type `T[]`

In addition, `Arrays.asList` is generic and infers the type parameter `T` from the type of its arguments. If only a single argument of array type is given, interpretation (2) takes precedence.

This means that when you write `Arrays.asList(new String[] {"x"})`, Java interprets this as a call of form (2) with `T = String`.

With multiple arguments there’s no confusion: Java always interprets it as a call of form (1), and infers `T` to be of type `String[]`.

So the solution, [as khelwood has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66564674/1968), is to disambiguate calls with a single argument, either by packing the argument into an additional array layer, or by explicitly specifying the generic type parameter `T`.